# Find Conditonal Variance of $y$ given $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, variance

Find the conditional variance of y given $x = \frac{1}{2}$

$$
f(x,y)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2}{3}(x+2y) \text{ for } 0<x<1,0<y<1  \\ 
0 \qquad \text{elsewhere} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

In order to solve this one must substitute in for $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus

$$f(\frac{1}{2}|y) =\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1+4y}{3}\qquad \text{ for } 0<x<1,0<y<1  \\ 
0 \qquad \text{elsewhere} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. $$

$$\Rightarrow E(\frac{1}{2}|y)= \int^1_0y(\frac{1+4y}{3})dy =\frac{11}{18} $$

$$\Rightarrow E(\frac{1}{2}|y^2)= \int^1_0y^2(\frac{1+4y}{3})dy=\frac{4}{9} $$

$$\Rightarrow \sigma^2_{\frac{1}{2}|y}=\frac{4}{9}-(\frac{11}{18})^2=\frac{23}{324}$$

Would this be the correct way to solve this problem according to what the question has asked for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize $g(y)=f(x,y)|_{x=1/2}$, so that $\int_0^1g(y)dy=1$.
Happily, in this case that integral is already $1$, so the normalizing factor is $1$.

Comment: So would my answer to the question need further improvement or editing in order to give a correct response to what was asked?